# How to jump to imported JavaScript file in IntelliJ/WebStorm

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm

Within a *WebWorker* JavaScript file the following are some imports for scripts in the same local directory:

```
importScripts("base64.js")
importScripts("cider_utils-no-exports.js")
```

I had expected to be able to jump to them by putting cursor within one of the filenames and hitting `CMD-B`. But that gave only a warning "Cannot find declaration to go to" :

[image]

I also tried "Goto file" But that brings up a dialog with an unrelated search.  So what is the way to jump to the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would require treating this method in a special way (like it's done for `require()` calls, for example). This feature is not currently supported, please vote for [WEB-13048](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13048) if you miss it.

For now, I can only suggest injecting **File reference** language into function argument, like

```
// language=file-reference
  importScripts('foo.js');
```

this should help

[image]

Comment: Oh that's just a fine workaround - except does that need to be done for _every_  `importScripts` ?

Comment: unfortunately yes:( You can't inject it in all methods because of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35166